# Derivative with respect to a tensor

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, tensors

I am trying to differentiate a tensor with respect to another one in *Mathematica*, but I can't do it. Down below is the code I am using:

```
$Assumptions = A \[Element] Arrays[{3, 3}, Reals]
B = A * A\[Transpose]
D[B, B]
```

And it would say:

> General::ivar: "A\ Transpose[A] is not a valid variable."`

How should I tackle this ?